How to use next/image inside react-vite application efficiently
Can i use next/image outside of next js app
for example in vite-react application.
when I install pnpm install next inside vite-react application,
installtion is successful, but its Image component (next/image) does not work in react-vite application
is there a way to make it work?
I installed
pnpm install next inside vite application
it did not work.


Can i use next/image outside of next js app

As the name indicates, no. next/image is specifically for NextJS apps which is mutually exclusive with Vite. They cannot be used together.
